# I'm trying to import Typescript files but when I compile it to Javascript I'm getting bad Errors from the web browser. exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, export

> TodoAppUI.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I have the  `export` keyword in every class.
For example:

```
export class mysclass {
public constructor(){}
}
```

I'm using this syntax to import but still not working

```
import TodoAppUI = require("./TodoAppUI");
```

This is my config file:

```
{


        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "commonjs",
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "removeComments": true,
            "preserveConstEnums": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "target": "es5"

        }, 
    "files": [
        "TodoApp.ts",
        "BaseService.ts",
        "TodoAppUI.ts"


    ]

}
```

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Comment: Your error seems related to a JS file, not a TS one. However you need to export a class only if you use it inside a scoped block like a module or a namespace. otherwise you just need to declare it as 
class mysclass {
public constructor(){}
}

Answer (score 0):

`module: 'commonjs'` in your config file tells compiler to compile the codes to an `commonjs` module in which you get a module like `const TodoAppUI = require("./TodoAppUI")` . If you want to use `import`, then fix the configFile with `module: 'ES6'`

Comment: I  Change it but still getting error on Chrome 
 Unexpected token export
now im getting error on this:  import { BaseService } from "./BaseService";

Comment: Changing config `module: es6` to `module: UMD` if you want run in browser.But it caused other problems. If you want to know more, read issues of github: [umd module compiler option doesn't have a fallback for global namespace](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8436)